pinning the messages window in lyx
so by mistake i dragged the message panel and now it as a seperate window i want it to be pinned to the buttom as default but couldnt find any way to do this, i use linux with kde 6
I've tried finding sources about it but couldnt find any.

Yes, that's a nasty hidden feature:

just double-click on the process header (black in your screenshot)
works with Win10



yea its just maximizing the window, even after disablimg the option to maximize using touble click it does nothing

Then there's a difference in behaviour between kde 6 an Win 10. I suggest to contact the Lyx developers, post a bug report etc.

so all i had to do was to go to /usr/share/lyx/ui move the "defaults.ui" file to somewhere else, try to open lyx (it wont open) and then move the file box with the ui being reset

@EladElmakias Fine. I suggest to reformulate your comment as an answer. Future readers will find it more easily, and a few might even vote for you.
